# Как правильно настроить расширение элементов окна?

Tags: java, javafx, разметка

есть окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно сделать так, что бы при уменьшении высоты окна не пропадал элемент Field

[image: Пропал TextField]

Также, нужно сделать, что бы при расширении окна элементы гармонично расширялись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код состоит из main класса

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;

public class webStart extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Browser");
        Parent content = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("web.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(content,1200,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Класса-контроллера:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Contorleer  {

    public TextField urlField;
    public WebView webViewer;

    WebEngine webEngine;

    @FXML
    private StackPane pane;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progresBar;
    String message;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchor;

    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.image.ImageView images;

    @FXML
    private GridPane grid;

    public void loadURL() throws IOException {
        webEngine = webViewer.getEngine();
        loadPage(urlField.getText());
        urlField.heightProperty();
        Worker<Void> worker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
        worker.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                urlField.setText(webEngine.getLocation());
                urlField.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        progresBar.progressProperty().bind(worker.progressProperty());
    }
    public void imageMouseListener(){
        loadPage("google.com");
    }
    public void loadPage(String url) {
        try {
            webEngine.load("http://"+url);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("eror");
        }
    }
}
```

ну и FXML файла:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
     <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
      <?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


    <StackPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" 
    prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="browser.Contorleer">
   <children>
      <GridPane>
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1200.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="1167.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="594.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="33.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="263.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="795.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="770.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="778.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="760.0" minHeight="2.0" prefHeight="14.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="46.0" minHeight="3.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <TextField fx:id="urlField" onAction="#loadURL"/>
        <ImageView fx:id="images" fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="51.0" 
       pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-image: 
      url('file:E:/img/home.png');" GridPane.columnIndex="1" 
      onMouseClicked="#imageMouseListener"/>
        <ProgressBar fx:id="progresBar" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="1175.0" 
        progress="0.0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <WebView fx:id="webViewer" prefHeight="584.0" prefWidth="1167.0" 
         GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <WebView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
         GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
     </children>
  </GridPane>
  </children>
 </StackPane>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо!

Comment: Измени коренвой контейнер на `BorderPane`. Сверху - текстовое поле, по центру - `WebView` и далее по ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!